# Connection established to MariaDB server, but couldn't get data into database?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

This is the whole php code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Connect to MariaDB Server</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?php
     $dbhost = 'localhost';
     $dbuser = 'test';
     $dbpass = 'pass';
     $dbname = 'databseName';
     $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

     if(! $conn ) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
     }

     echo "Connected successfully<br><br>";

     function add($url, $category){
         $sql = "INSERT INTO tt (url, category) VALUES ('$url', '$category');";
         if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
             echo "Recorded.";
         } else {
             echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
             }
      }

      if(function_exists($_GET['f'])){
         $_GET['f']($_GET['url'], $_GET['cat']);
      }

      mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I typed in "http://localhost/connect.php?f=add&url=www.google.com&cat=google" in my browser, this is the result:

```
Connected successfully

Error: INSERT INTO tt (url, category) VALUES ('www.google.com', 'google');
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /var/www/html/connect.php on line 24

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/connect.php on line 24

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_errot() in /var/www/html/connect.php:27 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/connect.php(32): add('www.google.com', 'google') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/connect.php on line 27
```

I tried a lot of other possible solutions I found online but none of them work. Please help, many thanks in advance!

Comment: please learn about sql injections and how to avoid with prepared statements (prepared statements are a good habit!)

Comment: For the record, your use of `f` is extremely dangerous. What happens when someone passes `f=unlink`?

Comment: Please Show the error meassage

Comment: Consider looking into a framework - you are trying to roll your own routing in a very dangerous way.

Comment: @Jens There is no other error message, just "Error: INSERT INTO tt (url, category) VALUES ('www.google.com', 'google');"

Comment: Have you tried to copy that Statement to a Client or the console ?

Comment: @Alex What's your db structure? Also output `mysqli_errno()`, that can help with diagnosing the error.

Comment: Yes, I'd tried that in console.

Comment: And you get an error too?

Comment: @ArmanP. The mysqli_error() and mysqli_errno() won't show in the browser.

Comment: No, it returns query ok.

Comment: @Alex Try to enable error reporting above all the script `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: @ArmanP. Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /var/www/html/connect.php on line 24

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/connect.php on line 24

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_errot() in /var/www/html/connect.php:27 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/connect.php(32): add('google', 'google') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/connect.php on line 27

Comment: @ArmanP. It outputs the above three error messages.

Comment: @ArmanP. Hey I solved the question already! Big thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function of:

```
function add($url, $category) {
    // code
}
```

You are trying to use the variable `$conn`. Which is defined *outside* of the function.

You should pass that variable into the function:

```
function add($url, $category, &$conn) {
    // code
}

if(function_exists($_GET['f'])){
    $_GET['f']($_GET['url'], $_GET['cat'], $conn);
}
```

You could just use `global $conn;` inside the function, but it is suggested to avoid using `global` entirely. It makes for messy and dangerous code conditions in larger projects. Less control. By passing the $conn by reference, you are specifically ensuring the right value is going to be used.

As a side note: prepared statements would be good to use for your SQL since you are putting passed in values which can have malicious SQL inside them.

As a side side note: thiswhole process you are making looks a bit precarious and lots of care should be taken to whitelist function names and set up. You may wish to move it all to a class too.

Comment: OMG thank you so much! I finally be able to insert data into my database! Yes, I'll use the prepared statements next time! Thank you!

Comment: I've overlooked a global variable as well from time to time... it happens! :) Many get fixed when moving things to a class though, since the `$conn` would have been setup as a `$this->conn` or `self::$conn`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that now. It is my homework and it is my first time coding in PHP, and I have a lot of other exams lately, so I'm going for the easiest solution.